# Force Plymouth to Show

Tags: boot, plymouth

How can I force plymouth to show for a certain amount of time?  I am going for a certain aesthetic and don't really care about boot time.

Comment: "I don't really care about boot time": you are kidding?

Comment: nope.  I am on a mission to make ubuntu look exactly like a mac.  This is what I have so far.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffh03x0cjmj3iza/Mac%20OS%20Catalina.png?dl=0